# getting error When using RenderMode in RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid

I have a problem. When I am using RenderMode in RadGrid , I got this error:

```
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
```

Parameter name: valueDescription: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: value
```

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
Stack Trace:

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: value] System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit.GetTypeFromString(String value) +3065878 System.Web.UI.WebControls.Unit..ctor(String value, CultureInfo culture, UnitType defaultType) +261
```

.

.

.

**This is my aspx:**

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="gvRad2" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="gvRad2_OnNeedDataSource"
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"
        AllowSorting="True"
        AllowFilteringByColumn="True"
        RenderMode="Lightweight">
        <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="PostLetterID" CommandItemDisplay="Top" InsertItemPageIndexAction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage">
            <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="PostLetterID" HeaderText="haha" ReadOnly="true"
                    ForceExtractValue="Always" ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" AllowFiltering="False"></telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            </Columns>
        </MasterTableView>
    </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I run the project as LocalIIS and the error disappeared.